# JWT token changes when passing through the GCP API gateway

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-api-gateway

I am sending a JWT token in api header. I designed this to pass through GCP api gateway and hit cloudrun service. But when passing through api gateway, the whole JWT token changes every time. There is no effect when I call the cloudrun directly without an api gateway. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several use cases

- If you consider that your Cloud Run requires an authentication, but the access to API Gateway doesn't, the API Gateway is able to generate an identity token, based on the service account in its configuration, and add it to the request forwarded to Cloud Run
- If you consider that your Cloud Run requires an authentication and you want to use API Gateway as authentication proxy (for instance, all the users that request the API gateway must be authorized by API gateway (by API key, by FirebaseAuth, by JWT token,...), but the users aren't directly granted on the Cloud RUn service, API Gateway is able to generate an identity token, based on the service account in its configuration, and add it to the request forwarded to Cloud Run
- If you consider that your Cloud Run requires an authentication and API Gateway is simply a passthrough to centralise the APIs definition, you can set in your `x-google-backend` definition, the [parameter `disable_auth` to true](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#disable_auth). That time, API Gateway won't generate an identity token and won't add it in the forwarded request. The identity token received in entry is forwarded to Cloud RUn (it must be a valid token for Cloud Run)

*Note: when API Gateway generate an identity token, the initial authorization token is [forwarded in a new header: `X-Apigateway-Api-Userinfo`](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticate-service-account#receiving_authenticated_results_in_your_api)*